# ¿Como puedo sumar tres checkbox en una casilla?

Tags: java, java-swing

Ya logre programar todo pero me falta la suma de los importes, básicamente al activar las casillas puedo poner números y al dar mostrar debo de hallar el importe y el subtotal que seria las suma de este y quiero eso saber como hallar el subtotal

[image: .]

[image]

[[image: 3]

acá un poco el código que use para programar lo demás pero solo me faltaría eso y no se como lo podria hacer o si modificar algo de lo que hice para lograr hacer que funcione todo

private void btnMActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    if(chk1.isSelected()){
       int precio = Integer.parseInt(txtp1.getText());
       int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(txtc1.getText());
        
    
       txti1.setText(""+ precio * cantidad);
    }      
 if(chk2.isSelected()){
       int precio = Integer.parseInt(txtp2.getText());
       int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(txtc2.getText());
       
   
       txti2.setText(""+ precio * cantidad);
    }

if(chk3.isSelected()){
       int precio = Integer.parseInt(txtp3.getText());
       int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(txtc3.getText());
       
    
       txti3.setText(""+ precio * cantidad);
    }
```

private void chk1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
  txtp1.setEnabled(false);

    txtc1.setEnabled(false);

    txti1.setEnabled(false);

    if(chk1.isSelected()){

        txtp1.setEnabled(true);

        txtc1.setEnabled(true);

        txti1.setEnabled(true);
       
       
        }
}                                    

private void chk2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    txtp2.setEnabled(false);

    txtc2.setEnabled(false);

    txti2.setEnabled(false);

    if(chk2.isSelected()){

        txtp2.setEnabled(true);

        txtc2.setEnabled(true);

        txti2.setEnabled(true);
        
       
      }  
}         
                       

private void chk3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
                                
   txtp3.setEnabled(false);

    txtc3.setEnabled(false);

    txti3.setEnabled(false);

    if(chk3.isSelected()){

        txtp3.setEnabled(true);

        txtc3.setEnabled(true);

        txti3.setEnabled(true);
        }
       
}
```

Quiero el seudocódigo para poder calcular el subtotal al presionar mostrar y solo que sume los checkbox que estén marcados, que si marco 2 y desmarco 1  pueda sumar este también al dar mostrar.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Seguir o copiar y pegar código de una imagen para probarlo suele ser... problemático. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Una buena pregunta siempre termina reabierta :)

Answer (score -1):

Has que el metodo calcular subtotal reciba parametros de cada checkbox, cuando se precione un checkbox estara en 1 y cuando no estara en 0, y el metodo calcularsubtotal recibira los parametros de los 3 y al calcular el precio de cada cosa lo multiplica por su parametro correspondiente entonces quedaria tipo:

```
public int funcioncalcularsubtotal(boolean zapatos,int precioz,int canz,bolean casaca,int precioc,int canc, boolean shortF, int precioShf, cantShf){
double subtotalT=0; 
subTotalZapatos=precioz*canz*zapatos;
subTotalcasaca=precioc*canc*casaca;
subTotalshortF=precioShf*cantShf*shortF;
subtotal=subTotalshortF+subTotalcasaca+subTotalZapatos;

return subtotal;
}
```

y simplemente muestra lo que le de subtotal, no ando seguro si necesita implementar hilos ya que se esta modificando mientras se esta ejecutando... Saludos me comentas si te funciono.